# How to use Mapbox geocoder in OpenLayers application?

Tags: openlayers, mapbox-gl-js

I want to use Mapbox geocoding services in OpenLayers 5 project. I'm using this method https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-geocoder  but it doesn't support Mapbox API

Answer (score 1):

There is option for custom provider. Here tensing geocoder is added. https://github.com/TensingUSA/ol3-geocoder/commit/1ef481e19c051da701d043954757be5939407d25

It will have to be modified with mapbox parameters.

Comment: There is also an example in https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-geocoder/tree/master/examples